# how to make page scroll down as a footer div expands large with slideDown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a footer area that is display:none by default. This bottom footer area holds things like the menu and social links.

In order to see this menu, you scroll down to the BOTTOM of the page (all the way, so you cant scroll any farther). there you see and click a button that says 'expand'. once you do that, the div beneath the expand button which holds the content animates with slideDown().

the problem is the page doesnt scroll along with bottom edge of the div as it animates downwards... so at first glance it looks like nothing happens until you realize you have to scroll down a little bit more. i want it to automatically scroll the page at the exact same speed/length that it animates.

heres the click function

```
$('#footer-click a').click(function() {
    if ($('#footer-inner').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('#footer-click a').html('Hide');
        $('#footer-inner').slideDown('medium');
} else {
        $('#footer-click a').html('Expand');
        $('#footer-inner').slideUp('medium');
    }
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `scrollTop()` to scroll the extra distance:

```
$('#footer-click a').click(function() {
    if ($('#footer-inner').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('#footer-click a').html('Hide');
        $('#footer-inner').slideDown('medium', function() {
            $('html').scrollTop( $('html').scrollTop() + $('#footer-inner').outerHeight() );
        });
    } else {
        $('#footer-click a').html('Expand');
        $('#footer-inner').slideUp('medium');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Of course, this will make it happen all at once at the end.  You might have to customize the animation to make it smooth.  (Let me think about it...)

**Edit:** OK what you might want to do is simply `show()` the footer, and then use animate to scroll the page down.  It gives the same effect.  You can close it the same way as before:

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer-click a').click(function() {
        if ($('#footer-inner').css('display') === 'none') {
            $('#footer-click a').html('Hide');
            $('#footer-inner').show();
            // Some browsers use html, some use body.  Use the bigger one:
            var scrollY = $('body').scrollTop()?$('body').scrollTop():$('html').scrollTop();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollY + $('#footer-inner').outerHeight()
            }, 'medium');
        } else {
            $('#footer-click a').html('Expand');
            $('#footer-inner').slideUp('medium');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Eeq26/4/

If there is a posibility the footer won't be at the very bottom, you would need an `if..then` to check if `scrollTop() == 0`, and use `slideDown()` in that case.

Comment: on your fiddle it doesnt move the page for some reason when you click expand. you can see the effect i mean here: http://www.pinkspage.com/us/home

Comment: You mean if there is content below your footer?

Comment: theres no content below the footer. the content IN the footer is hidden by default. i basically want it so when you click expand, the footer slides down and enlarges to full size, but while this is happening i want it to scroll at the same speed so you can visually see that the content is scrolling down. right now with the code the footer doesnt animate it just appears suddenly, and it also doesnt scroll (it seems to do that on your jfiddle as well)

Comment: Hmm, it's scrolling for me.  What browser are you using?  Looks like it works in Firefox, IE, but not Chrome.  I might have to come back to this later...

Comment: OK, looks like Chrome/Safari use `body` for scrollTop, while the others use `html`.  Example fixed.

Comment: you sir, are truly amazing. You have no idea what a nightmare my life is right now and i have clients calling me left and right needing stuff. im driving across country iwth all my belongings, 2 cats clawing at my face, trying to answer 'URGENT SITUATIONS'. thanks so much

Comment: Glad I could help.  You should get your cats de-clawed. :)